# Debugger in vb.net skips line

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a vb.net project, I didn't had chance to work on that kind of project so far, since I am using C# all the time exclusively.

I did some changes in the code and I set a breakpoint at one method, I want to see what I'll get from that method, but although I have breakpoint set, the debugger skips that line and goes to the next line.

Here is the code sample:

```
  Dim decryptEmail As String = DecryptData("myemail@yahoo.com")
        Dim encryptedEmail As String = "myemail@yahoo.com"
        Dim encrpytedPassword As String = "mypassword"
```

That's happening on page load event, and the debugged skips the 1st line automatically, and goes to the 2nd line right away. I want to know why is that happening.

Comment: If you're stepping through the code use F11 as opposed to F10 to step into the method.

Comment: yes, I just noticed that the breakpoint exists when the project is not started, and when I am starting the project, the breakpoint dissapears. Really weird

Comment: I rebuilded the solution. Sorry. @Peladao

Comment: It may be that VB can evaluate that expression at compile time; in that case you can't set a breakpoint on it because there is actually no code.

Comment: Good point Brian, we need to know what 'DecryptData' is. However, isn't an assignment statement always treated as code by the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, these sort of things can be caused by bugs in Visual Studio.
I usually just rebuild the solution. If that doesn't help, I exit and restart VS and reopen the solution. I have even had to reboot the computer once to end weird VS behavior.

Last but not least, if nothing else helps you could just enter a Stop statement before the line where you want a breakpoint.