# vb.net debugger skips line for debugging

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Earlier today I asked this question [debugger in vb.net skips line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511814/debugger-in-vb-net-skips-line) but I just found out something weird (or maybe that's normal for vb.net) about the project I am working on.
I am editing vb file, adding some methods.

Debugging the original file is working fine, I can step into the code and go through each line, line by line, without any problems. Now when I added a few methods debugger works really weird, check these two screenshots:

1. website is not started -> all breakpoints at place: http://gyazo.com/1077b7efbdb2b37174d5960cdff0bda5.png?1348160907
2. website is started -> breakpoint at 2nd line is missing: http://gyazo.com/3051303d6eb27af9ea13bd6e72b81a83.png?1348161507

Furthermore, when I added the methods to the file, now the debugging doesn't go line by line, but for example steps at the 1st line, and then when I click f10, it goes 20 lines further below, it doesn't go to the next line in the code. 
I am editing vb.net code for first time, I've been using c# exclusively, and I don't know if I need to modify something after editing the file so the debugger will work properly.

Original code:

```
Public Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private m_objFranchiseInfo As New clsFranchiseInfo

    Private Sub Login_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        Dim sEmail As String = Request.QueryString("email")
        Dim sPswd As String = Request.QueryString("password")



        If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sEmail) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sPswd)) Then

            If (sEmail.ToLower = "admin@mysite.com") Then
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                Session("UserName") = sEmail
                Session("Password") = sPswd
            Else

                Dim objService As New clsPropertyware
                With objService

                    .UserName = sEmail
                    .Password = sPswd
                    .Initialize()

                    If .TestConnection = True Then
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                        Session("UserName") = sEmail.ToLower
                        Session("Password") = sPswd
                        Session("OrgID") = .GetOrgID


                    Else
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("", True)
                        Session("UserName") = String.Empty
                        Session("Password") = String.Empty
                        Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
                    End If

                End With


            End If
        Else
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            Session("UserName") = String.Empty
            Session("Password") = String.Empty
            Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
        End If
    End Sub



    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim sEmail As String = Request.QueryString("email")
        Dim sPswd As String = Request.QueryString("password")

        If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sEmail) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sPswd)) Then

            If (sEmail.ToLower = "admin@mysite.com") Then
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                Session("UserName") = sEmail
                Session("Password") = sPswd
            Else

                Dim objService As New clsPropertyware
                With objService

                    .UserName = sEmail
                    .Password = sPswd
                    .Initialize()

                    If .TestConnection = True Then
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                        Session("UserName") = sEmail.ToLower
                        Session("Password") = sPswd
                        Session("OrgID") = .GetOrgID
                        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx")
                    Else
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("", True)
                        Session("UserName") = String.Empty
                        Session("Password") = String.Empty
                        Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
                    End If

                End With


            End If
        Else
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            Session("UserName") = String.Empty
            Session("Password") = String.Empty
            Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub LoginUser_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles LoginUser.Authenticate

        Dim szUserName As String = CType(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox).Text().Trim()
        Dim szPassword As String = CType(LoginUser.FindControl("Password"), TextBox).Text().Trim()

        If (szUserName.ToLower = "admin@mysite.com") Then
            e.Authenticated = True
            Session("UserName") = szUserName
            Session("Password") = szPassword
        Else

            Dim objService As New clsPropertyware
            With objService

                .UserName = szUserName
                .Password = szPassword
                .Initialize()

                If .TestConnection = True Then
                    e.Authenticated = True
                    Session("UserName") = szUserName.ToLower
                    Session("Password") = szPassword
                    Session("OrgID") = .GetOrgID
                Else
                    e.Authenticated = False
                    Session("UserName") = String.Empty
                    Session("Password") = String.Empty
                    Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
                End If

            End With
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub LoginUser_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoggedIn

        If (Session("UserName") = "admin@mysite.com") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/UploadValues.aspx")
        Else

            m_objFranchiseInfo.Clear()
            If (m_objFranchiseInfo.Load(Session("UserName")) = True) Then
                Session("FranchiseAgent") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szAgent
                Session("FranchiseAgent2") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szAgent2
                Session("FranchiseAddress") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szAddress
                Session("FranchiseCity") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szCity
                Session("FranchiseState") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szState
                Session("FranchiseZip") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szZip
                Session("FranchisePhone") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szPhone
                Session("FranchiseFax") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szFax
                Session("FranchiseEmail") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szEmail
            Else
                Response.Redirect("~\FranchiseInfo.aspx")
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

modified code:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private m_objFranchiseInfo As New clsFranchiseInfo

    Private Sub Login_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        Dim sEmail As String = Request.QueryString("email")
        Dim sPswd As String = Request.QueryString("password")



        If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sEmail) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sPswd)) Then

            If (sEmail.ToLower = "admin@mysite.com") Then
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                Session("UserName") = sEmail
                Session("Password") = sPswd
            Else

                Dim objService As New clsPropertyware
                With objService

                    .UserName = sEmail
                    .Password = sPswd
                    .Initialize()

                    If .TestConnection = True Then
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                        Session("UserName") = sEmail.ToLower
                        Session("Password") = sPswd
                        Session("OrgID") = .GetOrgID


                    Else
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("", True)
                        Session("UserName") = String.Empty
                        Session("Password") = String.Empty
                        Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
                    End If

                End With


            End If
        Else
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            Session("UserName") = String.Empty
            Session("Password") = String.Empty
            Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
        End If
    End Sub



    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim encryptedEmail As String = "myemail@yahoo.com"
        Dim decryptEmail As String = DecryptData("myemail@yahoo.com")
        Dim encrpytedPassword As String = "password"




        Dim sEmail As String = Request.QueryString("email")
        Dim sPswd As String = Request.QueryString("password")

        If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sEmail) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sPswd)) Then

            If (sEmail.ToLower = "admin@mysite.com") Then
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                Session("UserName") = sEmail
                Session("Password") = sPswd
            Else

                Dim objService As New clsPropertyware
                With objService

                    .UserName = sEmail
                    .Password = sPswd
                    .Initialize()

                    If .TestConnection = True Then
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sEmail, False)
                        Session("UserName") = sEmail.ToLower
                        Session("Password") = sPswd
                        Session("OrgID") = .GetOrgID
                        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx")
                    Else
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("", True)
                        Session("UserName") = String.Empty
                        Session("Password") = String.Empty
                        Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
                    End If

                End With


            End If
        Else
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            Session("UserName") = String.Empty
            Session("Password") = String.Empty
            Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub LoginUser_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles LoginUser.Authenticate

        Dim szUserName As String = CType(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox).Text().Trim()
        Dim szPassword As String = CType(LoginUser.FindControl("Password"), TextBox).Text().Trim()

        If (szUserName.ToLower = "admin@mysite.com") Then
            e.Authenticated = True
            Session("UserName") = szUserName
            Session("Password") = szPassword
        Else

            Dim objService As New clsPropertyware
            With objService

                .UserName = szUserName
                .Password = szPassword
                .Initialize()

                If .TestConnection = True Then
                    e.Authenticated = True
                    Session("UserName") = szUserName.ToLower
                    Session("Password") = szPassword
                    Session("OrgID") = .GetOrgID
                Else
                    e.Authenticated = False
                    Session("UserName") = String.Empty
                    Session("Password") = String.Empty
                    Session("OrgID") = String.Empty
                End If

            End With
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub LoginUser_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoggedIn

        If (Session("UserName") = "admin@mysite.com") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/UploadValues.aspx")
        Else

            m_objFranchiseInfo.Clear()
            If (m_objFranchiseInfo.Load(Session("UserName")) = True) Then
                Session("FranchiseAgent") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szAgent
                Session("FranchiseAgent2") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szAgent2
                Session("FranchiseAddress") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szAddress
                Session("FranchiseCity") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szCity
                Session("FranchiseState") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szState
                Session("FranchiseZip") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szZip
                Session("FranchisePhone") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szPhone
                Session("FranchiseFax") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szFax
                Session("FranchiseEmail") = m_objFranchiseInfo.szEmail
            Else
                Response.Redirect("~\FranchiseInfo.aspx")
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function DecryptData(
   ByVal encryptedtext As String) As String

        ' Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array. 
        Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)

        ' Create the stream. 
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        ' Create the decoder to write to the stream. 
        Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
            TripleDES.CreateDecryptor(),
            System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the plaintext stream to a string. 
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

    Private Function TruncateHash(
    ByVal key As String,
    ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()

        Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        ' Hash the key. 
        Dim keyBytes() As Byte =
            System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)

        ' Truncate or pad the hash. 
        ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
        Return hash
    End Function

    Sub New(ByVal key As String)
        ' Initialize the crypto provider.
        TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize \ 8)
        TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize \ 8)
    End Sub

    Public Function EncryptData(
    ByVal plaintext As String) As String

        ' Convert the plaintext string to a byte array. 
        Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte =
            System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)

        ' Create the stream. 
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        ' Create the encoder to write to the stream. 
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
            TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(),
            System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string. 
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Is your build configuration set to `Debug` or `Release`?

Comment: Build configurations is set to Debug

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144880/visual-studio-2010-debugger-skipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting using the ASP.net development server, I have seen this happen when that process is still executing code even though Visual Studio has stopped. When you start a new debugging session it tries to follow both sessions. I think this may happen when you hit the stop button rather than closing your browser window and there are long running or asynchronous processes.

Try right clicking on the ASP.net development server icon in the taskbar and selecting stop, then start debugging.